# Angular ignore certificate signature

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm looking over some old angular code that looks like this:

```
import { Headers, RequestOptions, Http, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
```

I have one function:

```
getInfo() {
 var info: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({});
 info.headers = new Headers();
 info.headers.append('myInfo', 'infoData');
 return this.http.get("http://myurl.com/api/info", info);
}
```

I'm getting an error saying:

"Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid..." with the url being "https://myurl.com/api/info".

In postman I can make the call to http if I got to settings and disable "SSL certificate verification". Is it possible to do the same thing in Angular?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this. My suggestion would be since your problem looks like development environment problem is to generate CA certificate, then certificated for your website and it's API. After that you need to add generated CA certificate to list of your trusted certificates and you're done.

If you however run on publicly available server, you might want to take a look at [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) - they provide free SSL certs.

Comment: i see, i don't really have access to the backend side unfortunately. However could this be caused by forcing the calls from http to https on the backend side? So if someone where to stop the redirection could in theory work for http calls?

Comment: Yes, without https you will not be needing any certificate. But I would strongly advise to get the backend server to update/fix their certificate instead.